# Error cloning database unable to update the following flags: cloudsql.enable_password_validation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am attempting to clone a database. **I was able to previous clone it in the console**, but now I want to create a small script to automate this and it fails with the following error message:

> (gcloud.sql.instances.clone) [ERROR_RDBMS] unable to update the following flags: `cloudsql.enable_password_validation`

If I attempt to clone it in the console, I get the same error shown above.

I looked up the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/troubleshooting#flags) and `enable_password_validation` does not seem to be in the list of supported flags, which would explain why it can't update it.

If I run `gcloud sql instances describe my-instance`, I don't see the flag in question.

But running on the source instance:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_settings
```

yields this row in particular:

| name | setting | unit | category | short_desc | extra_desc | context | vartype | source | min_val | max_val | enumvals | boot_val | reset_val | sourcefile | sourceline | pending_restart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cloudsql.enable_password_validation | off | NULL | Customized Options | Sets whether to enable Cloud SQL password validation. | NULL | superuser | bool | configuration file | NULL | NULL | NULL | on | off | /pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf | 3 | False |

Any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an [ongoing](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/MqpDy4VdUKuQkw1GXPTo) issue with password validation in Cloud SQL Postgres instances. The issue involves the exact flag that is giving you problems `cloudsql.enable_password_validation`:

> Diagnosis: Affected postgres instances from a recent release have the following flag set and are unable to remove or disable this flag: cloudsql.enable_password_validation=on. This flag does not appear in Cloud Console, and attempting to disable flag via gcloud returns error where the flag is not recognized or supported. Password validation occurs on every new client connection but is limited to 50 QPS, and thus higher rates will return errors.

When did this issue start occurring? Have you also attempted to clone the database since then? This is due to the issue receiving several updates. If you continue experiencing issues, you could [open a support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) case with GCP as the status page recommends.

**EDIT (2/24/2022)**

I wanted to update this answer. The issue seems to be resolved as shown in the status page of Google Cloud:

> The issue with Cloud SQL has been resolved for all affected instances as of Tuesday, 2022-02-22 14:30 US/Pacific. We thank you for your patience while we worked on resolving the issue.

If you still see this error, you can update the question confirming that it was not resolved as part of the outage resolution.

Comment: @QuantumLicht were you able to confirm if the issue continues happening as the status issue changed?